# Algorithms to check if string has unique characters in Scala. Why is O(N2) verison quicker?

Tags: scala

I implemented two versions of the algorithm in Scala (without using sets, by the way). A first one :

```
def isContained(letter: Char, word: String): Boolean =
    if (word == "") false
    else if (letter == word.head) true
    else isContained(letter, word.tail)

def hasUniqueChars(stringToCheck: String): Boolean =
    if (stringToCheck == "") true
    else if (isContained(stringToCheck.head, stringToCheck.tail)) false
    else hasUniqueChars(stringToCheck.tail)
```

which is in O(N2).

And a second one :

```
def hasUniqueChars2Acc(str: String, asciiTable: List[Boolean]): Boolean = {
    if (str.length == 0) true
    else if (asciiTable(str.head.toByte)) false
    else hasUniqueChars2Acc(str.tail, asciiTable.updated(str.head.toByte, true))
  }

def hasUniqueChars2(str: String): Boolean = {
    val virginAsciiTable = List.fill(128)(false)
    if (str.length > 128) false
    else hasUniqueChars2Acc(str, virginAsciiTable)
  }
```

which is in O(N).

But when testing, the second version takes as much as 20 times the duration of the first one. Why? Is it related to the `.updated` method ?

Comment: Yes, `updated` will need to copy a part of the list. Consider using `scala.collection.immutable.BitSet` for `asciiTable` instead.

Comment: Also `tail` on String is pretty slow.

Comment: Thank you both, I didn't know bitsets. It's much better using them : only 2 to 3 times longer compared to the O(N2) version. What could I do to not use `tail` ?

Comment: You could try converting the `String` to a `List[Char]` first. Or probably even better, try rewriting the explicit recursion to some kind of `fold`.

Comment: Since `get(n)` is `O(n)` for lists your `asciiTable(str.head.toByte)` is a really really costly operation. Also, the ascii characters start with `32` (space), you are doing the initial 31 iterations for no reason at all.